# Declaration of 'int accidents[5]' shadows a parameter error

Tags: c++, function, parameters, shadow

I'm new to C++ and can't find any way around this error. As far as I know I'm not overloading any variables to create a conflict with naming(which was the closest thing to a cause i could find online). Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int getNumAccidents(string);
int findLowest(int accidents[]);
int main()
{
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
 int input;
 int accidents[ARRAY_SIZE];
 int counter = 0;
 string regions[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"North", "South", "East", "West", "Central"};
 string name;
 string lowestRegion;
 int lowest = 1000000000;
 while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
  name == regions[counter];
  accidents[counter] = getNumAccidents(name);
  counter++;
 }
 findLowest(accidents);
 system("PAUSE");
 return 0;
}

int getNumAccidents(string name)
{
 int input;
 validate:
 cout<<"Enter the number of accidents that took place in the "<<name<<" region in the                  last year:"<<endl;
 cin>>input;
 if (input < 0)
 {
  system("CLS");
  cout<<"Invalid input: the number of accidents can not be negative.";
  goto validate;
 }
 return input;
}

int findLowest(int accidents[])
{
 const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
 string lowestRegion;
 int accidents[ARRAY_SIZE];
 string regions[ARRAY_SIZE] = {"North", "South", "East", "West", "Central"};
 int lowest = 0;
 int counter = 0;
 while (counter < ARRAY_SIZE)
 {
  if (accidents[counter] < lowest)
  {
   lowest = accidents[counter];
   lowestRegion = regions[counter];
  }
  counter++;
 }
 cout<<"The "<<lowestRegion<<" region had the least accidents in the past year at " <<lowest<<" accidents."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: If you actually read the whole error, it will very likely tell you the line and variable name that is giving you an error.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? and don't use `goto`.

Comment: `goto` isn't bad in itself, but there's no reason to use it here.

Comment: There are very few valid reasons for using `goto` in C++ application. None of which fit for someone that is new to C++.

Comment: This is **not** an error. A compiler that refuses to compile it does not conform to the language definition. The meaning of the code is well defined, although it is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
        int findLowest(int accidents[])
    //                      ^^
        {
         const int ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
         string lowestRegion;
         int accidents[ARRAY_SIZE];
 //               ^^
```

You have two `accidents` in your `findLowest`

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I'll set this as the accepted answer as soon as i can.

Comment: +1 for "two accidents".  Programs shouldn't have any *accidents*. :-)